# How to get variable outside from inside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i had developing area calculator functionality but here i am facing an issue. i am getting total inside the function and now i wan to use this total value outside the function.
i had declared outside like this   var total = 0 total1 = 0 Total = 0 Total1 = 0;
when i call the these variables i am getting only zero . i am not getting anything from the function.
How can i call the value from inside of the function to out side.
For ref please find my below code.

```
<select
                  name="unit"
                  class="areacalc-select"
                  data-bind="options: $parent.unitsArray, value: selectedUnit"
                >
                  <option value="m">m</option>
                  <option value="mm">mm</option>
                  <option value="cm">cm</option>
                  <option value="inches">inches</option>
                  <option value="feet">feet</option>
                </select>
```

var total = 0,Total = 0,

```
  $("#areaWidth,#areaHeight").keyup(function () {
    var textValue1 = $("#areaWidth").val();
    var textValue2 = $("#areaHeight").val();
    total = textValue1 * textValue2;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
    document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = total;
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".areacalc-select").on("change", function () {
        var measurement = document.querySelector(".areacalc-select").value;
        console.log(measurement);
        if (measurement === "m") {
          Total = total;
          document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = Total;
          document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = Total;
        } else if (measurement === "mm") {
          Total = total * 3;
          document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = Total;
          document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = Total;
        } else if (measurement === "cm") {
          Total = total * 4;
          document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = Total;
          document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = Total;
        } else if (measurement === "inches") {
          Total = total * 5;
          document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = Total;
          document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = Total;
        } else {
          Total = total * 6;
          document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = Total;
          document.getElementById("totalvalue").innerHTML = Total;
        }
        console.log(typeof Total);
      });
    });
  });
```

document.getElementById("area-calc-total").innerHTML = Total;

Comment: Your code should be a [mcve], not your whole application.

Comment: Okay Andy i will change

Comment: this question does not need to use an example of 430 lines of code.

Comment: @ Mister Jojo i am now learning so could you please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly.

In JavaScript variables declared inside functions are scope bounded.

If you want to use a variable you declared inside a function, return the value. If you have multiple values you want to return, put them in an object and return the object.

If you want to do it in a more interesting way, check closures in JavaScript, where the parent variable is accessible to child function, so you can wrap child function inside of parent function.